# Initialization of pointer of type BOOL warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm getting a new warning of  Initialization of pointer of type 'BOOL *' (aka 'bool *') to null from a constant boolean expression.  This is the code causing an warning i haven't seen before?

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO]) {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the method `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` The `isDirectory` is a return by reference parameter, that is it returns a Bool that indicated if the path is a directory or not.

From the Apple Docs:

> isDirectory: Upon return, contains YES if path is a directory or if the final path element is a symbolic link that points to a directory, otherwise contains NO. If path doesn’t exist, this value is undefined upon return. Pass NULL if you do not need this information.

Use:

```
BOOL isDirectory;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:& isDirectory]) {
    if (isDirectory) {
        // Code for the directory case
    }
    else {
        // Code for the file case
    }
    ...
}
```

If you don't want to know if the path points to a directory just use:

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path
```